# Get info about current simulator device

Tags: ios, swift

As I know if I want to know which type of device is using (iPod, iPhone 4, iPhone 5 etc) I should use (swift):

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().model
```

But this code works only with real devices and if working simulator it just says: `iPhone simulator`. And never mind which type of. How I can get information about currently simulator device?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that information? If you need to know the screen size, use UIScreen. Otherwise, the different device simulators have very similar characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the screen size to determine what device the simulator is running as:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
let screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

If you want to get the version of the OS etc. you can use UIDevice.currentDevice() to access additional details:  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemName

Comment: Other options are no more?